# Getting no of characters fit to a Printdocument Line

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi

I am doing a winforms billing sytem using c# .I am facing a problem in setting the width of string in  the printdocument.

I want to split the Item description to multiple lines if its length Exceeds a particular length.The width of Qty,Rate,Amount is fixed,But the width of item description can very according to the page width.

```
 **Item Description       Qty   Rate   Amount**

  1.Item Description-     1.0   12.00   12.00
    One 
  2.Item Description-     3.0   20.00   60.00
    Two
```

How can i get the no of string fit in a particular rectangle region,so that i can split thew item description.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using printdocument control the print page event use the PrintPageEventArgs variable to configure the rectangle(the margin bounds property) and page settings and so on...

Comment: terry.my problem is, let i have to display the string from point 0(left margin) to point 150.i want to know how can i calculate no of strings that can fit in 150 point.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the trick?

```
const int AllowedCharactersPerLine = 16;
string example = "this is a very long string that we want to divide to fit to several lines";
string StringWithRows = "";
int n = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < example.Length; i++)
{
   StringWithRows += example.Substring(i, 1);
   n++;
   if (n == AllowedCharactersPerLine)
   {
       n = 0;
       StringWithRows += Environment.NewLine;
   }
}
```